# Testing component internal methods on click

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I have a simple code and would like to see, if button is pressed, does onPress get called. That all without enzyme, because it does not work on react 16.

```
export default class SimpleThing extends Component {

    onPress = () => {
        console.log('Will it get called?')
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Button onPress={this.onPress} />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

and test would be something like that, but it does not work

```
describe('SimpleThing', () => {
    it('calls onPress when Button is pressed', () => {
        const component = renderer.create(
            <SimpleThing />,
        )
        const instance = component.getInstance()
        const spy = jest.spyOn(instance, 'onPress')
        expect(spy).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
        const tree = component.toJSON()
        tree.children[0].props.onPress()
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
})
```

How can it be done with jest? Tried also with replacing onPress with jest.fn(), but it had no effect on component.toJSON() and wrong function got called.